# Show image saved in the storage directory(data/data/yourapp/folder) in phonegap/cordova

Tags: android, image, cordova

I'm working on a hybrid app with **Cordova/phonegap** using **AngularJs** and some plugins and trying to show an image stored in the storage directory the path is:

"file:///data/data/com.myapp/images/dot.png"

In the html page I just try to access this file with

`<img src="file:///data/data/com.myapp/images/dot.png">`

but it never show anything:

I checked the file with the cordova plugin file and is there!

any tips or work around for showing images from this directory?

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path? Like `<img src="images/dot.png">` assuming the image is located in www/images/dot.png...

Answer (score 1):

use following plugin to open images,audio file, video and pdf files.

```
https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2
```